# cannot import name AmazonKendraRetriever from langchain

Tags: langchain, amazon-kendra

I cannot import 'AmazonKendraRetriever' from langchain due to the following errors

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 from langchain.retrievers import AmazonKendraRetriever

ImportError: cannot import name 'AmazonKendraRetriever' from 'langchain.retrievers' (/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/retrievers/__init__.py)
```

My python version is 3.10.10. I have tried fixing it by pip installing langchain==0.0.201 based on some discussion on a github thread, but that doesn't fix the issue. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the kernel from conda_pytorchp310 to conda_python3 and that fixed the issue. Running the code from a Sagemaker jupyterLab notebook.